# Docker getting "cURL error 7: Failed to connect to fmhlocal.com port 443: Connection refused" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, docker

So i had to make a Curl in order to get refresh token in laravel passport and I am using docker. This is what I am doing :

```
 $response = Http::asForm()->post('https://fmhlocal.com/api/oauth/token', [
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => 'the-refresh-token',
        'client_id' => '2',
        'client_secret' => 'TaRtD8Z6Jiy7Bb2jBolFyfafv68vNHKbLf037jH1',
        'scope' => '',
    ]);

    return $response->json();
```

and this is what I am getting :

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to fmhlocal.com port 443: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://fmhlocal.com/api/oauth/token
```

now I dont know where and how to handle it !

Comment: The remove side refused the connection request. How would you want to handle that? It's not necessarily an error caused by you even. BTW: A [mcve] would be fine, in particular whether it's specific to PHP, Laravel, Docker or cURL.

Comment: https://fmhlocal.com  redirects to http://ww16.fmhlocal.com.

Comment: @giles-bennett Its a local path .

Comment: Any updates on that?